# How to calculate Spearman's rank correlation between two datasets

Tags: python, correlation

If we have:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({"A":[34,12,78,84,26], "B":[54,87,35,25,82], "C":[56,78,0,14,13], "D":[0,23,72,56,14], "E":[78,12,31,0,34]})
Y = pd.DataFrame({"A":[45,24,65,65,65], "B":[45,87,65,52,12], "C":[98,52,32,32,12], "D":[0,23,1,365,53], "E":[24,12,65,3,65]})
```

How do we calculate **Spearman's Rank Correlation** between the two datasets (but not within each dataset), so that in the end we have a 5x5 matrix? 
Like this:

```
    A  B  C  D  E
A   .  .  .  .  .
B   .  .  .  .  .
C   .  .  .  .  .
D   .  .  .  .  .
E   .  .  .  .  .
```

Comment: If you want to compute correlation of matching columns only, shouldn't you end up with a vector with 5 components? (as opposed to 5x5 matrix)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant that in a way that we dont have both datasets on both axis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using pandas' `concat` and `corr` function you can turn this into a one liner by putting everything together into one `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd

X = pd.DataFrame({"A":[34,12,78,84,26], "B":[54,87,35,25,82], "C":[56,78,0,14,13], "D":[0,23,72,56,14], "E":[78,12,31,0,34]})
Y = pd.DataFrame({"A1":[45,24,65,65,65], "B1":[45,87,65,52,12], "C1":[98,52,32,32,12], "D1":[0,23,1,365,53], "E1":[24,12,65,3,65]})

pd.concat([X,Y], axis=1).corr(method="spearman").iloc[5:,:5]
```

Note that in my example I gave the second set of columns a different name to make them more easily distinguishable. Using pandas' indexing features you could come up with a more sophisticated way of picking out the desired rows/columns from the correlation table than my `.iloc[5:,:5]`, but in this case it works.

---

EDIT TO ADD RESULTS:

[image]

Comment: In order to make the columns distinguishable, you can also use .add_prefix:

    pd.concat([X.add_prefix("X_"), Y.add_prefix("Y_")], axis = 1)

Comment: Thank you, this coincides with the results I got in my code as well. I asked this with a second thing in mind, why does spearman's give me the exact same values as pearson's?

Comment: It doesn't (for me) - see updated answer with outputs

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick! Probably might be made shorter though:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import linregress


X = pd.DataFrame({"A":[34,12,78,84,26], "B":[54,87,35,25,82], "C":[56,78,0,14,13], "D":[0,23,72,56,14], "E":[78,12,31,0,34]})
Y = pd.DataFrame({"A":[45,24,65,65,65], "B":[45,87,65,52,12], "C":[98,52,32,32,12], "D":[0,23,1,365,53], "E":[24,12,65,3,65]})

row = 0
col = 0
m = np.zeros( (len(X), len(Y) ))
for key_x, val_x in X.iteritems():
    for key_y, val_y in Y.iteritems():
        if( col == 5 ):
            col = 0 
        m[row][col] = linregress(val_x, val_y).rvalue
        col += 1
    row += 1

print m
```

To calculate the correlation, I am using linregress, but there are other alternatives such as:

- `numpy.corrcoef`
- `pandas.DataFrame.corr`

And probably some others too ;)

Comment: Hi thank you for answering. I am looking specifically for Spearman's rank correlation, as the data I'm using doesn't fulfill the assumption of normality